# How to sort list of records with different types when compiler wrongly assumes types should be all strings?

Tags: elm

I have a helper function to sort a list of records in 6 different ways.

```
sortResults : SortableField -> SortOrder -> List RecsysResult -> List RecsysResult
sortResults sortOnField sortOrder results =
    let
        reverse =
            case sortOrder of
                TypeAlias.ASC ->
                    False

                TypeAlias.DESC ->
                    True

        field =
            case sortOnField of
                TypeAlias.MHID ->
                    .mhid

                TypeAlias.NAME ->
                    .name

                TypeAlias.SCORE ->
                    .score

        sortedResults =
            List.sortBy field results

        newResults =
            if reverse then
                List.reverse sortedResults
            else
                sortedResults
    in
        newResults
```

Even without making a call to said function, the compiler gives me an error.

> The 2nd argument to function `sortBy` is causing a mismatch.
>
> 42|             List.sortBy field results
>                                     ^^^^^^^ Function `sortBy` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
>
> ```
> List { mhid : String, name : String, score : String }
> ```
>
> But it is:
>
> ```
> List RecsysResult
> ```
>
> Hint: Problem in the `score` field.

RecsysResult is just a type alias for a record

```
type alias RecsysResult =                                                             
    { name : Name, mhid : Mhid, score : Score }
```

`Name`, and `Mhid` are just type aliases for Strings, while `Score` is a type alias for Float.

So basically the compiler expects a list of `{ name : String, mhid : String, score : String }`, but I'm working with `{ name : String, mhid : String, score : Float }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`field` has different types in all branches (`... -> String` or `... -> Float`), so Elm replaces it with `... -> String`.

```
    newList =
        case sortOnField of
            TypeAlias.MHID ->
                List.sortBy .mhid results

            TypeAlias.NAME ->
                List.sortBy .name results

            TypeAlias.SCORE ->
                List.sortBy .score results
```